# Laravel 5.1 codification problems. Getting ï¿½

Tags: utf-8, laravel-5

I'm having problems with utf-8 and Laravel 5. I know is a popular problem, but I read and read without success. This is what I have:

- Tables and columns in database (mysql) are configured as utf8_unicode
- So, in Laravel, in config/database.php

  > 'charset'   => 'utf8',
  >   
  > 'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
- In my forms I always use

  > accept-charset="UTF-8"
- And in the head

  > meta charset="utf-8"
  >
  > Content-Type:text/html; charset=UTF-8
- My php files are encoded in utf-8

But I'm still getting (around 0.1%) of characters as **ï¿½**

Is there any way to solve this? I'm doing something wrong?

Thanks.